# Display alert when the tab button is clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a tabbed page with five tabs. My problem is OnAppearing function is not working when the tab button is clicked but when you use swipe to navigate the function works.

For example I have a tab named settings and it is linked to my **settings.xaml** I added a DisplayAlert on my OnAppearing function in my **settings.xaml.cs**. When you click the tab button for settings the display alert will not appear however when you use swipe to navigate to settings page the alert will appear. I want to be able to display an alert when the page appears or navigated how can I do that?

Tabbed Page:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TBSApp.View"
        x:Class="TBSApp.Tabbed_Page.TabPage"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        BarBackgroundColor="#fff"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#bbbbbb"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#fc5661">
<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
<NavigationPage Title="Dashboard" Icon="home.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:Dashboard />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="CAF" Icon="caf.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:CAFMenuPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Customer" Icon="retailer.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:RetailerMenuPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SettingsMenuPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Account" Icon="account.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:AccountMenuPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

Settings.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
     base.OnAppearing();
     DisplayAlert("Settings Page", "You are in settings page", "Got it");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it. You are right. By swiping between tab pages it always works but when I tap on tab buttons sometimes it works as expected and sometimes it is not working. Probably this is a bug in xamarin.forms.

There is a workaround that works correctly in both situations. You can use **CurrentPageChanged** event in your TabbedPage like this:

```
private void TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var navigationPage = CurrentPage as NavigationPage;

   var currentPage = navigationPage.CurrentPage;

   if(currentPage.GetType() == typeof(AboutPage))
   {
        DisplayAlert("CurrentPageChanged works correctly", "about page", "ok");
   }
   else if(currentPage.GetType() == typeof(ItemsPage))
   {
        DisplayAlert("CurrentPageChanged works correctly", "items page", "ok");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works I hope they fix the bug I though there is something wrong with the code

Comment: Your welcome, I hope so. If you can, please report this bug to the Xamarin team.